# How to install pod file in Flutter?

Tags: ios, flutter, cocoapods

When I run Flutter app in Xcode, the app does not run.

Error: pod not installed.

I want to run app on iOS device.

Where does Android Studio expect to find CocoaPods? Could the problem be that Android Studio can't find the path to CocoaPods?

**Logs :**

Warning: CocoaPods not installed. Skipping pod install.

CocoaPods is used to retrieve the iOS and macOS platform side's plugin code that responds to your plugin usage on the Dart side.

Without CocoaPods, plugins will not work on iOS or macOS.

For more info, see https://flutter.dev/platform-plugins

To install see https://guides.cocoapods.org/using/getting-started.html#installation for instructions.

CocoaPods not installed or not in valid state.

Error launching application on iPhone 12 mini.

Answer (score 0):

First go to terminal, then go to ios directory in project, then run 'pod install'.
If this doesn't work then run 'pod update'. This will definitely work.

Answer (score 0):

Open Terminal in your system and do all these steps one by one :

- sudo gem install cocoapods-deintegrate
- sudo gem install cocoapods-clean
- cd  (your project path)
- pod deintegrate
- pod clean
- rm Podfile
- pod init
- pod install